# systemd-resolved browse for mdns services

Tags: systemd, dns, avahi, systemd-resolved, mdns

Can systemd-resolved be used to browse for mdns services the same way like avahi-browse?

For example:

```
$ avahi-browse _smb._tcp
+   eno1 IPv6 PC1                                      Microsoft Windows Network local
+   eno1 IPv6 PC2                                      Microsoft Windows Network local
+   eno1 IPv6 PC3                                      Microsoft Windows Network local
+   eno1 IPv6 PC4                                      Microsoft Windows Network local
```

But on another machine in the same network, resolved is used but querying all machines for a given service is not working:

```
$ resolvectl --protocol=mdns service _smb._tcp.local
Resolve call failed: All attempts to contact name servers or networks failed
```

But a direct query involving the hostname is working:

```
$ resolvectl --protocol=mdns service PC1._smb._tcp.local
PC1._smb._tcp.local: PC1.local:445 [priority=0, weight=0]
                          fe80::e4c2:d456:7856:45f1%4       -- link: eth0
                          (PC1/_smb._tcp/local)

-- Information acquired via protocol mDNS/IPv6 in 139.7ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
```

What do I miss here? Or is resolved not made for what I want?

Comment: It would be better if you could ask this on systemd github page. However resolvectl requires enabling individual mdns services in all machines in local network and publishing dns-sd  for all machines. But as per this it works. https://daenney.github.io/2021/11/14/replacing-avahi-exploring-dnssd/